# using a require js based module with relative paths

Tags: requirejs

I am trying to use a library called g.js (https://github.com/nodebox/g.js), which is a graphics package.  The script file "g.js" is the entry point file which is "requiring" other files using the syntax:

```
// Utility functions
g.bezier = require('./util/bezier');
g.color = require('./util/color');
g.geo = require('./util/geo');
g.math = require('./util/math');
g.random = require('./util/random');
g.svg = require('./util/svg');
```

My question is... how to use this set of library files within my html / javascript files?

For my part, I tried the following:

Loaded require.js in my html file:

```
<script src="scripts/require.js" data-main="scripts/main"></script>
```

My main.js looks like this:

```
require.config({
baseUrl : "scripts",
paths : {
  'jquery' : 'jquery-1.11.1',
  'lodash' : 'libs/lodash',
  'module_g_test' : 'module_g_test'
},
packages: [
  {
    name: "g",
    location: "g.js-master/src",
    main: "g"
  }
]
});

require(['jquery', 'module_g_test'], function($, g_test) {
  $(function() {
    console.log("basic stuff ready!");
    g_test();
  });
});
```

Finally, I am trying to use the graphics libraries in my module script file

```js
define(['g'], function(g) {

  var testModule = function() {
    var x = g.Path.prototype;
    console.log(x);
  };

  return testModule;
});
~
```

No matter what I do, I am unable to load the internal javascript files accessed by g.js.  I get a requirejs error:

> Error 
>   Module name "util/bezier" has not been loaded yet for context: _ http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a library written in commonjs style that uses browserify. Clone the repository and:

1. run `npm install`
2. run `npm run browserify`
3. link the script from `build/g.js` in your site

The distribution version has an UMD implemented so it should work with RequireJS.

Comment: All these are new stuff to me. Will follow through your suggestions :)

Comment: Read more here http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/ and then here http://browserify.org/

Comment: Thank you. I know a little bit of AMD and require.js, as I started using them off late.  But absolutely no clue about common js, NPM and Browserify. Will read and try.

Comment: 1. I installed nodejs and npm
2. ran the npm install in the cloned copy of g.js
3. when I run the npm run browserify, I get errors.

Comment: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
npm ERR! weird error 127
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"

npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

Comment: it works now.  Had a problem with node vs nodejs commands (a debian specific problem).